# Rounding to 2 decimal place. java

Tags: java, rounding

I am trying to round 113.10285 down to 113.10 but all I get is 113.1
How do i round it to 2 decimal places with the 0.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the display format differently?

Comment: System.out.printf("%.2f", 113.10285);